# Java ArrayList - Value, and not Item Removed from ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, while-loop

I am trying to remove dollar-value items from a cart. For example, if I have 4 items in my cart, I want to be able to remove item #4 and then have the program carry on with the remaining three items. However, in my output you'll see that although I request that item #4 be removed, it removes the item with the value of 4 (as in $4.00) but not item #4.

```
System.out.print("Would you like to delete an item - y/n: ");
String deleteResponse = textReader.nextLine();
while ((!deleteResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) && (!deleteResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("n")))
{
    System.out.print("Sorry - we need a y/n: ");
    deleteResponse = textReader.nextLine();
}

if ((deleteResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("y")))
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Provide an item to delete: #");
    int removalRequest = numberReader.nextInt();
    while (removalRequest > cartItems.size())
    {
        System.out.print("That number is out of range - try again:# ");
        removalRequest = numberReader.nextInt();
    }
    int y = 0;
    while (y < cartItems.size())
    {
        if (cartItems.get(y) == removalRequest)
        {
            cartItems.remove(y);
        }
        else
        {
            y++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nItem #" + removalRequest + " has been removed.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Thanks - no items will be deleted.");
}
System.out.println("\n********** Here is your final list of items **********");
System.out.println();

for (counter = 0; counter < cartItems.size(); counter++)
{
    System.out.println("Item #" + (counter + 1) + ": " + dollarFormatter.format(cartItems.get(counter)));
}
// find subtotal
double subtotal = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.size(); i++)
{
    subtotal += cartItems.get(i);
}
```

The output should look like:

> [image: Correct Output]

Instead of removing #4 which is $5.00, it removes item #3 which is 4.00. Should I not use the ArrayList while loop? Should I use a for loop instead?

My output is:

> [image: My output]

Comment: No need for the `if/else` you can simply do: `cartItems.remove(removalRequest);`

Comment: `if (cartItems.get(y) == removalRequest)` -> here you remove the item that has **value** `4.00`. You want to remove item at **index** `removalRequest - 1`

Comment: what exactly a cartitem is?, Set,Array???

Comment: Use an `Iterator`

Comment: Thanks, Backslash. The note about the indexes helped me fix it! Is there a way to refresh an arrayList? For example, if I wanted the user to be able to add a second set of values, how do I get the program to "forget" the first set of values?

Comment: Perhaps `cartitems = new ArrayList()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List has two `.remove` methods: `.remove(Object o)`, which removes the object itself, and `.remove(int index)` which removes the object at a given index. This is not confusing in the case of a `List<String>`:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("Nate");
names.add("Sunmi");
names.add("Tony");
for (String name : names) {
    System.out.println(name); // Sunmi, Nate, Tony
}
System.out.println("-------");
names.remove("Nate");
for (String name : names) {
    System.out.println(name); // Sunmi, Tony
}
System.out.println("-------");
names.remove(0);
for (String name : names) {
    System.out.println(name); // Tony
}
```

However, in the case of a `List<Integer>` it is confusing. The objects in the list will always be `Integer` objects, so to remove an element at a particular index, you will need to cast it as an `(Integer)` or an `(int)` depending if you want to remove an element or the element at an index:

```
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(21);
    numbers.add(35);
    for (Integer name : numbers) {
        System.out.println(name); // 1, 21, 35
    }
    System.out.println("-------");
    numbers.remove((Integer) 21);
    for (Integer name : numbers) {
        System.out.println(name); // 1, 35
    }
    System.out.println("-------");
    numbers.remove((int) 0);
    for (Integer name : numbers) {
        System.out.println(name); // 35
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

cartItems.remove(removalRequest);

You have the index of the item to remove so just remove it. lol.

Comment: Indexes are zero-based. You need to use `cartItems.remove(removalRequest - 1);`, since user input starts from 1

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using a simple example, hope it will make clear

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> a =new ArrayList();
        a.add(4);
        a.add(1);
        a.add(2);
        a.add(4);
        for(int b: a)
        System.out.println(b);
    a.remove(3);
    for(int b: a)
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

In above code i am removing element at `index 3` and the `output i get is 4 1 2` which i correct according to you question.